# imenu does not work for python mode or c++ mode

Tags: emacs

The imenu works for me in `emacs-lisp-mode-hook`. But when I try the following for the python or c++ mode, it does not work:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (add-to-list
              'imenu-generic-expression
              '("Sections" "^#### [ \\(.+\\) ]$" 1))
             (imenu-add-to-menubar "Position")))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (add-to-list
              'imenu-generic-expression
              '("Sections" "^//// [ \\(.+\\) ]$" 1))
             (imenu-add-to-menubar "Position")))
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of what you are trying to match, are you trying to match this kind of string `#### [ Some-section ]`?

Comment: @Iqbal Ansari: exactly

Comment: Please don't quote your lambdas!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that both these modes (assuming you are using the builtin `python-mode`), set `imenu-create-index-function` (the function used to create index) to `imenu-default-create-index-function`. This function in turn tries to use the values of `imenu-prev-index-position-function`, `imenu-extract-index-name-function` to extract the imenu, it does not use the `imenu-generic-expression` if the the two variables are set (see the definition of `imenu-default-create-index-function`, in `imenu.el`). That is why the values you are setting is not used. What we can do here is define a custom function that uses both `imenu-default-create-index-function` and `imenu-generic-expression`, combines their results and returns it. Then we can set the value of `imenu-create-index-function` to our custom function. Below is an example of such a custom function

```
(defun my-merge-imenu ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((mode-imenu (imenu-default-create-index-function))
        (custom-imenu (imenu--generic-function imenu-generic-expression)))
    (append mode-imenu custom-imenu)))
```

Then we can set this as the value of `imenu-create-index-function` in major-mode hooks, eg. for python-mode

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-to-list
             'imenu-generic-expression
             '("Sections" "^#### \\[ \\(.*\\) \\]$" 1))
            (imenu-add-to-menubar "Position")
            (setq imenu-create-index-function 'my-merge-imenu)))
```

Similar solution should work for `c++-mode`.

A note about the regular expressions used: There is an error in your regular expression, since `[` is a metacharacter you will need to escape it to match normal `[`, you will also need to escape `\` since you are in a string so the correct regex string will be `"^#### \\[ \\(.*\\) \\]$"`